# Change static model pose in `PostUpdate`

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I'm working on a System plugin in Gazebo Garden and I need to move a model in the `PostUpdate` callback.

I found the `SetWorldPoseCmd` function, but it requires a not constant Entity Component Manager and it cannot be used.

What is the correct way to set a new position for static objects?

I tried with this, but as expected it does not work:

```
gz::math::Pose3d newPose(mCalibX,mCalibY,mCalibZ,mCalibRoll,mCalibPitch,mCalibYaw);

gz::sim::EntityComponentManager ecm;
ecm.CopyFrom(_ecm);

mModel.SetWorldPoseCmd(ecm,newPose);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28559/change-static-model-pose-in-%60postupdate%60/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87579/myzhar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think the main problem is that you're trying to set the model's pose form `PostUpdate`. The `PostUpdate` callback has a read-only access to the ECM. This is where systems update their internal state, not the state of the ECM. The `PreUpdate` is where systems are allowed to update the ECM and that's where you should try to set the pose of the model. See https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/7/createsystemplugins.html for more info.

Also, you shouldn't copy the ECM since any modifications you make to the copy will not affect the rest of the systems in the simulation.

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2022-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87579/myzhar/) on 2022-11-22**:
This is a really interesting note. I could not understand why ecm was read only in `PostUpdate`, but I was not considering the `PreUpdate` callback and it's scope. Thank you for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Myzhar, my suggestion is to call `SetWorldPoseCmd` in the next `PreUpdate`, as `PreUpdate` provides a non-`const` reference to `EntityComponentManager`. As you correctly note, `PostUpdate` provides a `const` reference; as far as I know, this is by design.

---

Originally posted by [jaguilar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/115785/jaguilar/) with karma: 11 on 2022-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87579/myzhar/) on 2022-11-22**:
Thank you. I figured out my error now.